# XML Download works in emulator but not on phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, webclient

I am downloading an XML file from a site I created and it works fine on the emulator; however, it doesn't work at all on the phone. It comes back with a web exception error and an IO error...and the error property from the HttpsCompleted event says error the remote server returned an error. File not Found. BUT this works on my emulator.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://.../SessionInfo.xml"));

    }

    private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument doc = null;
        string results = null;

        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);
            List<XElement> xelem = xdoc.Root.Elements() as List<XElement>;

            results = e.Result;

            var sessions = from x in xdoc.Descendants("Session")
                           select new
                           {
                               ID = x.Descendants("ID").First().Value,
                               TITLE = x.Descendants("Title").First().Value,
                               TIME = x.Descendants("Time").First().Value,
                               DESCRIPTION = x.Descendants("Description").First().Value
                           };

            foreach (var wd in sessions)
            {
                sessionsList.Add(new Session(wd.ID, wd.TITLE, wd.TIME, wd.DESCRIPTION));
                Debug.WriteLine("Session ID is {0}, Title is {1}, Time is {2}", wd.ID, wd.TITLE, wd.TIME);
            }
        }

        SessionInfoList.ItemsSource = sessionsList;
```

XML Looks like:

```
<request><Session><ID>1234-1234-1234-1234</ID><Title>Session Title</Title><Time>10:00AM-11:30AM</Time><Description>Some description.</Description></Session></request>
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question; but is your phone able to access the file from the build-in webbrowser?

Comment: @Kolky yea i tried and the xml comes up fine in the browser

Comment: is it possible to route the actual device through fiddler on your PC? (you can with some devices). For example like this [iPhone example](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/01/monitoring-iphone-web-traffic-with.html)? I'd be interested in knowing if the 'phone is right, and it was File not Found.

Comment: @Marc Gravell going to try it...

Comment: @MarcGravell That didnt work it never captured the traffic from my phone.

Comment: have you tried retrieving the contents from any other URI? Just to double check it's not an issue with the server or a typo in your code.

Comment: That is vexing, but it was worth a try.

Comment: @MattLacey not surprisingly a different uri from w3schools works...i wonder why its not working for mine though but works on the emulator? hmmmm...

Comment: @MarcGravell it is vexing...thanks for your help...

Comment: @MArcGravell try this if you want to run fiddler and observe traffic for WP7 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/01/09/debugging-windows-phone-7-device-traffic-with-fiddler.aspx

Comment: Is the sender server sending back the right content type? one of my coworkers said that you can get nailed from the content type on a network connection and not necessarily through the emulator...

Comment: @ChrisKoenig As far as I know it is...all I am doing is downloading an xml file from an ftp server...how can I check it?

Comment: Try downloading via Fiddler and see what you get back. If you can send me the info I can try to look at this for you. Chris.Koenig@Microsoft.com

Comment: If you have access to the web server log files, you should be able to see what request is hitting the server. That may help determine why the request is failing.

Comment: Do you have a warning from wp7 browser when you try to download the file ? Maybe a certificate issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Code like this should be prohibited because you risk the NullReferenceException :

```
TITLE = x.Descendants("Title").First().Value
```

Then, emulator uses internet connection of your computer, so if you use the same connection with your phone the problem is related to your phone, not related to your code.